# Sprite Kit Load Large Background

Tags: sprite-kit

Hey guys I'm using sprite kit to develop my game. I just want to create a big world for my player to roam around. But when I use large tile images of 1024 X 768 size it uses a lot of memory which I don't want for sure.

In my game the player as the ability to move in all directions. The camera is centered on the player. I've converted my tiles into 128 X 128. I've loaded all the tiles and added them to the array as in apple's adventure game. But, I want to load only those tiles which are at a particular distance (suppose x =1024 and y =768) from the player. And those tiles which are farther than that specific distance should be removed from the parent.

Is there a way to achieve this? And I'm open to all suggestions. Please Help. 
Thank You.

Comment: you might want to try the Kobold Kit tilemap renderer, it only renders visible tiles on screen and you can use the Tiled Map Editor to design your maps

Comment: Have you read the Apple spritekit documentation:
https://developer.apple.com/LIBRARY/IOS/documentation/GraphicsAnimation/Conceptual/CodeExplainedAdventure/AdventureArchitecture/AdventureArchitecture.html

Comment: Is there something specific that you don't understand about what you are trying to achieve ? You have described what you want. I'm not clear on what the issue is. What have you tried ?

Comment: @prototypical yes! What I want to know is how can I get the position of each tile.

Comment: Each tile has it's position of x,y. Do you mean how do you calculate where each tile goes ? It seems you might need to take a step back and read the documentation and try a few things. This is not a quality question as you aren't really stuck, you just need to take the time to learn.

Comment: @prototypical I want to know how to add only the selected tiles on the scene depending upon their position with respect to the player.

Comment: Right, which is why I am saying that you are describing what you want and you seemingly have no idea how to do that. That points to a lack of understanding of basic programming concepts, not a single question where you are stuck on something.

Answer (score 0):

I am currently working on a library for a tile scroller, it's not totally finished but it may suit your needs. It's using a Tableview datasource pattern to ask for the nodes, with a logic for node reuse included, it will going to be asking you for the tiles before showing them, and it will remove the not showed ones. Take a look at it:

[RPTileScroller](https://github.com/raspu/RPTileScroller)

I take some effort to make it the most efficient possible, but mind, I am not a game developer. I tried it with my iPhone 5 with random colors tiles of 10x10 pixels, and is running on a solid 60 fps.